# Word Frequency Looping

Tags: java, charts, java.util.scanner, word-frequency

The goal of this code was to create a program using main method java to analysis a piece text which has been entered from a user.

They do this by entering the text into a scanner which is then analysed by the program. The analysis is to produce word frequency, mean length and also print out the results in a form of a asterisks chart, were a single "*" represents 1 words.

For example " Birds can maybe fly" should output this results:

```
Enter Text:
Birds can maybe fly
Birds can maybe fly
3 letter words: 2
5 letter words: 2
mean length: 4.0
3 letter words: **
5 letter words: **
Enter Text:
```

But instead I'm getting this

```
Enter text: 
Birds can maybe fly
Birds can maybe fly
3 letter words: 2
3 letter words: *
mean lenght: 4.0
3 letter words: 2
3 letter words: **
mean lenght: 4.0
5 letter words: 2
5 letter words: *
mean lenght: 4.0
5 letter words: 2
5 letter words: **
mean lenght: 4.0
Enter text:
```

Is there a way to alter my code so it outputted what was seen within the first section instead of what I'm getting in the second.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Freq
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true)
        {

            System.out.println("Enter text: ");

            String s;
            s = scan.nextLine();
            String input = s;
            String strippedInput = input.replaceAll("\\W", " ");

            System.out.println("" + strippedInput);

            String[] strings = strippedInput.split(" ");
            int[] counts = new int[6];
            int total = 0;

                for (String str : strings)
                    if (str.length() < counts.length)
                        counts[str.length()] += 1;
                for (String s1 : strings)
                    total += s1.length();   

                for (int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++){    
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(i).append(i + " letter words: ");
                    for (int j = 1; j <= counts[i]; j++) {


                        sb.append('*');
                        System.out.println(i + " letter words: " + counts[i]);
                        System.out.println(sb);
                        System.out.println(("mean lenght: ") + ((double) total / strings.length));


        }}}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops are mixed, so you are printing too many things, and sometimes at the wrong time. You should split your loops.

First you want to output only the counts by length :

```
for (int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++){    
   System.out.println(i + " letter words: " + counts[i]);
}
```

Then you want to output the mean length :

```
System.out.println(("mean length: ") + ((double) total / strings.length));
```

Finally you want to output the asterisks :

```
for (int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++){    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(20);
    sb.append(i);
    sb.append(" letter words: ");
    for (int j = 1; j <= counts[i]; j++) {
        sb.append('*');               
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```